# Может ли переменная в функции видеть переменную вне функции?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

```
def func():
    url = 'google.com'
    n = requests.get(url)
    b = BeautifulSoup(n.text, 'lxml')
    g = b.find('tbody').text
    v = g[19:24]
    q = s.get()

# Сам адрес и веб - часть кода не важна.
w = Tk()
w.title('func')
w.geometry('650x500')
s = Entry(w, width=25,text=q)
s.grid(column=2, row=0)
```

Как сделать так, чтобы переменная q видела переменную s без переноса переменной s в функцию?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

добавьте `return q` в конец функции, а в `Entry` напишите `text = func()`

```
def func():
    url = 'google.com'
    n = requests.get(url)
    b = BeautifulSoup(n.text, 'lxml')
    g = b.find('tbody').text
    v = g[19:24]
    q = s.get()
    return q

# Сам адрес и веб - часть кода не важна.
w = Tk()
w.title('func')
w.geometry('650x500')
s = Entry(w, width=25,text=func()`
s.grid(column=2, row=0)
```